# Error: initialization with '{...}' is not allowed for object of type "const MyClass"

Tags: c++, initialization, simd

Basically I have a wrapper around a SIMD structure that goes like this:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
   MyClass();

   __m128 SIMD;
};
```

I saw that in the DirectXMath SIMD math library from Microsoft they can do things like:

```
const XMVECTOR SinCoefficients0    = {-0.16666667f, +0.0083333310f, -0.00019840874f, +2.7525562e-06f};
```

where **XMVECTOR** just wraps around something like this:

```
union
{
  float f[4];
  __m128 entry;
};
```

I also tried to use a union with an array, but it still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 4):

In order to be able to use aggregate initialization, you need to remove the user-defined ctor and make sure all members are public:

```
struct MyClass
{
   __m128 SIMD;
};
```

Please read [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) which explains what an aggregate is and how the initialization works.